# Joining two models/controllers to allow two views on one page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed this [simple-task-board codeigniter app from github](http://oscardias.github.io/Simple-Task-Board/). The app has 3 main pages

1. a dashboard which displays links to the projects
2. a project view which displays links to the tasks
3. a task view with information on the individual task

The project details are set up in their own models and controllers as are the tasks. As it stands the project view shows a list of tasks but in order to add a new task it has to pass you to another view loaded from the tasks MVC.

My question is what is the best way to get the 'add tasks' form on the project view. I am relatively new to MVC but I know that I should not be trying to what I am asking with the current set up i.e. I should not be trying to load a view from one controller in another. Would the best strategy be to try and join the two separate MVCs together or should I give up on trying to do this and rewrite the whole thing from scratch?

I did try using a library to pass the controller class from one MVC to the other but ended up with many database errors. I am assuming this was not a good plan?

---

Update - extra code added:

```
public function tasks($project_id)
{
    $this->load->helper('stb_date');
    $this->load->helper('tasks');

    // Check permission
    if(!$this->usercontrol->has_permission('project', 'tasks'))
        redirect('dashboard');

    // Load tasks
    $this->load->model('task_model');
    $tasks = $this->task_model->get($project_id);

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        if ($task['status'] == 0) {
            $data['stories'][] = $task;
        } elseif ($task['status'] == 1) {
            $data['tasks'][] = $task;
        } elseif ($task['status'] == 2) {
            $data['tests'][] = $task;
        } elseif ($task['status'] == 3) {
            $data['done'][] = $task;
        }
    }

    // Load project info
    $this->load->model('project_model');
    $project = $this->project_model->get($project_id);

    $this->title = "Project: {$project['name']}";
    $this->menu = 'dashboard|edit_project|new_task';

    $data['project_id']    = $project_id;

    $data['current_user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');

    $db_users = $this->project_model->get_related_users($project_id);
    $users = array();
    foreach ($db_users as $user) {
        $users[$user['id']] = $user;
    }
    $data['users'] = $users;

    // Load text helper to be used in the view
    $this->load->helper('text');

    // Load View
    $this->load->view('task_board', $data);


    //new code added here
    $task_data['parent_id']      = 0;
    $task_data['title']          = '';
    $task_data['description']    = '';
    $task_data['priority']       = '2';
    $task_data['due_date']     = '';

    $project = '1';
    $task_data['project_id'] = $project;
    $task_data['users']      = $this->task_model->get_related_users($project);
    $task_data['user_id']    = $this->session->userdata('user');
    $task_data['tasks']      = $this->task_model->get_hierarchy($project);

    if($this->error)
        $task_data['error'] = $this->error;
    $task_data['task_data'] = $this->load->view('task_add',$task_data,true);
}
```

Comment: The variables are passed to the views this way: you assign them to an array, like you have done, then pass them to the view method in their load class. That class then runs `extract ()` on that array, giving each of the array indexes it's own variable space (in the scope of the view method, though CI also -- maddeningly -- adds it to a global class, too)

Comment: At the end of your code, you are returning the data (html) from the view and assigning it back to the `$task_data` variable, but then you don't do anything with it.  It's hard to debug this way -- I don't have access to your code and I've not ever used the github project you are working with -- but probably your last line should be (after `$task_data['task_data'] = $this->load->view('task_add',$task_data,true);` which should be `$task_board_data['task_data'] = $this->load->view('task_add',$task_data,true);`): `$this->load->view('task_board',$task_board_data);`

Comment: You Sir are a scholar and a gentleman! This works, albeit with a hundred errors but hopefully I can debug those or hide them :) You have made me a very happy man

Comment: Any errors/notices/warnings indicate something it's expecting but not getting, so let me know if you need more help. It gets a lot easier once you understand a couple of the concepts I think you just learned.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out the errors were from the single_task template. To get around this I removed the first `$this->load->view('task_board', $data);` and then edited the last two lines to update the $data variable `$data['task_data'] = $this->load->view('task_add',$task_data,true); $this->load->view('task_board', $data);` still with the `<?php echo $task_data; ?>` in the view. Everything works but a big part of me thinks this is probably very 'hacked' together so please let me know if this is ugly code

Comment: Why don't you update me on where you are at now. I have been on vacation from work and basically computers since 12/20. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CI quite a lot and at the moment and somewhat like it but please note if you are just starting with MVC. The company that used to maintain it is looking for a new owner: http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter.

As for your question, this view looks like it's the one with the form you are wanting to copy/move: https://github.com/oscardias/Simple-Task-Board/blob/master/application/views/task_add.php

That's all pretty easy, but lines 91-93 have some hidden ids you likely won't have on the project view page. You don't get it until you choose a view. So you'll probably want to rewrite it slightly to include a drop-down list of projects or something to add the task to.

I would probably call that task_add.php view in the projects page so you don't have two copies. If the $project_id exists, show the hidden field, otherwise the dropdown of projects.

There isn't really a hard association between views and controllers or models. Typically the controller is the middle man, controlling the data that the view gets (and that is usually provided by a model).

Comment: Thanks for the post. The headsup about lines 91-93 is very helpful and I will look in to this. I have tried calling the task_add.php view in the projects page by both calling the view in the projects controller and also by passing the view to a variable and passing that in to the projects view. Neither work as they error with loads of undefined variables. My understanding of MVC is that these undefined variables are defined but in the tasks MVC rather than the project MVC and can't be seen? SHould I manually go through and re-define the variables in the project MVC?

Comment: MVC is a name for the entire design pattern. The part that is passing in the variables is the controller. The missing variables can be seen in the task controller, https://github.com/oscardias/Simple-Task-Board/blob/master/application/controllers/task.php, for example line 99 `$this->load->view('task', $data);`

Comment: You'll just need to add that to the controller where you added the view call, probably https://github.com/oscardias/Simple-Task-Board/blob/master/application/controllers/dashboard.php. What I would do is set up all the necessary `$data` (probably should call it $task_data for clarity), and then do this `$data['task_data'] = $this->load->view('task_add', $task_data, true);` about line 27 -- the last argument returns instead of echos the view html.

Comment: Then in the view https://github.com/oscardias/Simple-Task-Board/blob/master/application/views/dashboard.php you'll add `<?php echo $task_data; ?>` wherever you want it to appear.

Comment: Hi Hans. I need the view in the task_board view so I have adapted your comments but I get the error that $task_data is not defined (same if I use $data). Was there some basic step I should have added? If I copy and paste the $data definitions from the add method from the task controller I get a array to string conversion data base error? I can fix this by adding `$project = '1';` as I think this is done by the hidden fields on page view as you mentioned previously. However upon fixing that I get the same error that $task_data is not defined. ARGH I must be missing something very basic

Comment: I have added my current code for the tasks method in the project controller in case this helps. Only other thing I added was the echo statement in the [task_board view](https://github.com/oscardias/Simple-Task-Board/blob/master/application/views/task_board.php)